# Running Jar in Remote Access VS Jar in Shared Folder?

Tags: shared-directory

I have a jar in SERVER-A that reads from a file within SERVER-A. When I Remote SERVER-A (Remote Desktop Connection) and run it, it works fine.
But when I run the same Jar from a shared folder of SERVER-A via my local machine(not SERVER-A) it can not find the file.

I tried to print the current directory of the jar when its is running. 
1. When running from Remote access to SERVER-A i got "E:\ISO_Tester", This is the correct path.
2. When running from Shared folder of SERVER-A i got "C:\Windows" which I think is from my local machine instead of SERVER-A.

How can I make the jar read from the server when its being accessed from shared folder?
P.S. I'm using environment variable for the file location to be read.

```
String propFile=System.getenv("OTHERS_HOME") + "\\conf\\FILE_TO_READ.txt";
```

Comment: Find out what fail first.  Is it simply the current directory not correct? Then it is not the JAR's problem.  Writing a little batch file to run the JAR with proper current directory should work

Comment: The problem is when I try to read the FILE_TO_READ.txt from the code above. I'm using an environment variable for the path, and running the jar from shared folder, the error says that the file is not found, because it's looking in my local directory instead of the server's directory. it's probably because of the System.getenv is there an adjustment I can do to handle this scenario?

Comment: Still have no idea what your problem is.  Why can't you setup a correct OTHERS_HOME env variable then?

Comment: System.getenv is using my local machine's enviroment when using shared folder but it should read the environment of Server-A since the jar is in there.

Comment: what?! Why? you are running on machine B of course it is getting environment variable of machine B.  Why do you think it will run as it is run in Server-A? `"E:\ISO_Tester"` can mean totally different thing on machine B.

Comment: The scenario is this. I have a program that do something. It can only do it in Server-A because it's the only one with firewall allowed to perform it. Now, normally we remote access to this machine and run the jar there, but more and more people needs to run it and we cannot provide access to all of them. So I though of putting it in a shared folder but still within Server-A for it to work.

Comment: No it wont.   If you run it on machine-B, it runs on machine B. Period.  Share folder does not and should never do such kind of magic for you.  If you want something to run in server a but be able to trigger from other machine, there are lots of alternatives.  For example, make the program a simple web app, and allow people to trigger it remote

Comment: or try to google something like "windows remote run command"

Comment: Hmmmm, I thought it would work. There is a web for it but still under development and will take time. Do you know anyother way to do it?